# django delete button for comments?

Tags: django, button, comments

I have problem with deleting comments.
in my movies_details.html I have

```
{% render_comment_list for object %}
```

I have rewrited comments/list.html in my project templates folder and it looks like

```
<div class="comment_start">
  <div class="comment">
    <table>
    {% autopaginate comment_list 5 %}
    {% for comment in comment_list %}
      <tr>
        <td>
           {{ comment.comment }} 
        </td>
        <td>
           (from <strong><i><u>{{ comment.user }}</u></i></strong> <br> {{ comment.submit_date|timesince }} ago)
           <br>
           {% if user.is_authenticated and comment.user == user %}
             {% url mysite.views.delete_own_comment comment_id=comment.id as delete_url %}
             <a href="{{ delete_url }}">Delete</a>
           {% endif %}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {% paginate %}
  </div>
</div>
```

and in view, path is mysite/views, I have delete_own_comment view

```
def delete_own_comment(request, comment_id):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, id=comment_id)
    if comment.user.id != request.user.id:
        raise Http404
    perform_delete(request, comment)
```

when I click on delete button it just refreshes the page without deleting the comment and I don't know where is the problem

Comment: First shouldn't it be "{% url 'mysite.views.delete_own_comment' comment_id=comment.id as delete_url %}" ? Then your delete_own_comment view returns no rendered template, so clicking on your Delete button should return a white empty page no ? Could you provide more informations, for ex your server log, and maybe your webbrowser console content ?

Comment: Depending on the version of Django depends on if you need to include the single quotes or not so that could indeed be a problem. I would also suggest throwing some print statements in your delete function to see if it's even reaching there. Would be helpful to see the preform_delete() functions code.

Comment: What does perform_delete do?

Comment: Any luck with this question after 1 year? What does perform_delete()?